# Java Group objects by values in object's list

Tags: java, java-stream

### Problem

I have a list of objects like:

```java
Class MyObj {
  private List<Integer> categories;
  private String name;
}
```

I want to map the list of objects to a `Map<Integer, List<MyObj>>` using a single stream chain.

### Example

```java
MyObj obj1 = new MyObj("name1", Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));

MyObj obj2 = new MyObj("name2", Arrays.asList(1, 4, 3));

MyObj obj3 = new MyObj("name3", Arrays.asList(4));

List<MyObj> objsList = Arrays.asList(obj1, obj2, obj3);

// Here is what Im trying to accomplish:
// a map like -> **{1: [obj1, obj2], 2: [obj1], 3: [obj1, obj2], 4: [obj2, obj3]}**

Map<Integer, List<MyObj>> = objsList.stream
...help
```

Looking for a map -> **{1: [obj1, obj2], 2: [obj1], 3: [obj1, obj2], 4: [obj2, obj3]}**

I think the answer is obvious, but I cant seem to get it to work and having a hard time searching. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can stream the `List` from every `MyObj` and collect `Integer` and `MyObj` as pair and then use [Collectors.groupingBy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-)

```
 Map<Integer,List<MyObj>> result = objsList.stream()
            .flatMap(obj->obj.getCategories().stream().map(i-> Map.entry(i,obj)))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey,Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue,Collectors.toList())));
```

**Note :** [Map.entry](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entry-K-V-) is from java 9, you can use [new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Integer, MyObj>(i, obj)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.SimpleEntry.html#SimpleEntry-K-V-) for java 8

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was something like this